# Suggestions for designing a modular iOS project?

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit

*I read several questions on programmers.stackexchange.com to determine if this question is better asked there. I think this question belongs on SO, but I'm not completely sure.*

I have a basic knowledge of Objective-C and UIKit. I have read, a few years ago, most of *Cocoa Programming for OS X (2nd Edition)* by Aaron Hillegass; this is where the majority of my knowledge stems. The rest is from various sites, SO questions, the SDK documentation, and small personal projects (both OS X and iOS).

I am starting an iOS (specifically, iPhone) project for the university at which I work. This application will have distinct sections with distinct functionality. Some examples of "sections" would be: a virtual student ID card, current semester's class schedule (for the user), a campus map, etcetera. I want to be able to add new sections easily in future versions of the application. Thus, I want to design the project such that a section is an independent, from the main project, group of code (as much as possible).

In addition to being able to add new features by creating new modules, I want the project to be usable by more developers that just myself. That is, I want other developers on my team to be able to develop new modules for the application by following a "best practice."

Currently, I am basing my project around a `UITabBarController` with my "modules" being new `UIViewController`s and NIBs. I get the feeling that this might not be an optimal way of establishing my project. Thus my question:

What are some best practices for such a project as I have described?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. UIViewControllers are a good way to break this up.

UITabBarControllers are often awkward when you have a lot of options; a welcome screen with a table view of possibilities might be more expandable. See, for example, Facebook's left panel or the built-in Settings app.

I typically find that the hard part about reuse in iOS projects is not the view controllers (which are typically well isolated) but the underlying infrastructure such as that for network requests, data storage, account management, etc. You might want to start with an existing framework for this (like, say, Parse or RestKit), or at least look at how they break things up.

On the topic of good, reusable iOS design, you might find [Matt Gemmell's post about API design](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/) helpful, if not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for the tableView recommendation. TabViews are really only good if have >=5 views.

Comment: I'm using Grails for the server side framework (for better or worse). My current plan with the tab view is to have a "more" button that leads to a table view for the less important(?) modules. I'd like to do a springboard type interface, but writing one from scratch is a bit above me right now and I haven't found a third party component that I like (and I hear one might be available in iOS6).

Comment: Just read your edit. I like the suggestion of the Settings app interface.

Comment: I think no matter what you've read about in iOS 6, a springboard-type UI from scratch will still require significant work. In addition, apps have been rejected for similar interfaces under guideline 10.5 "Apps that create alternate desktop/home screen environments or simulate multi-app widget experiences will be rejected"

Answer (score 2):

- establish conventions for coding style and resource location.
- develop static libraries.
- if your static libraries require their own resources (which can be a necessary pain), you may want to use bundles for your resources to minimize resource collisions.
- centralize your build configuration files, rather than attempting to define each setting in each project (use xcconfigs).

then you can configure these libraries as dependencies in your app projects, and build, link, and copy appropriately.

one important note: i often err towards C and C++ symbols in these cases (where applicable) because ObjC symbols (and what they reference)cannot be stripped. this can reduce a lot of 'binary fat' where not used. so your 'core' libraries and libraries which deal mostly with symbols declared in other libraries (e.g. system libraries) may be in C and C++, and your higher level abstractions and derived types may be in ObjC.